# IE8 doesn`t get canvas element

Tags: html, canvas, getelementbyid, var, excanvas

I have canvas code like below:

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


  var imageObj = new Image();

  imageObj.src = 'images/floor1.jpg';


  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 610, 290, 0, 0, 610, 290);
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(62, 66, 66, 25); /* rectangle F sold */
    context.rect(221, 66, 66, 25);
    context.rect(327, 66, 66, 25);
    context.rect(488, 66, 66, 25);
    context.rect(62, 181, 66, 25);
    context.rect(186, 181, 66, 25);
    context.rect(363, 181, 66, 25);
    context.rect(488, 181, 66, 25);
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.stroke();
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.getElementById('out').src = dataURL;
  };
```

But this doesn`t work in IE8.
I try to add explorercanvas code:

```
   < script src="excanvas.js"></script >

    if (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager) != 'undefined') {
    myCanvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(myCanvas);
    }
```

but this doesn`t work. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

IE 8 does not support the `canvas` element.

http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas

Answer (score 0):

Your function seems to be recursive. You attached a function to draw `imageObj` on load event of same(`imageObj`). Please fix it by removing recursive call.

More than all above, IE8 not support Canvas

Canvas element ✘
2D context ✘
Text  ✘

Comment: i know canvas in IE8 don`t work. but i found this script "explorercanvas" http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/ and try to use it